# Error using React Native hooks, facebook, firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, firebase, react-native

I have a problem with react-native, I am trying to login with facebook using the expo-facebook and firebase libraries, it loads everything well and it starts session well, but when it loads the following screen the following comes up:

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>   1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>   2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>   3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>   See https://facebook.com/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Button, Text, StatusBar, LayoutAnimation, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Toast } from 'native-base'

import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const app = {
  id: APP_ID,
  name: APP_NAME,
}

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  }
  facebook = async () => {
    Facebook.initializeAsync(app.id, app.name)
    const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(app.id, {
      permission: 'public_profile',
    })
    if ( type == "success" ) {
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential( token )
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    }
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
  }
  render() {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut()
    return <View>
        <Button title="Log in with facebook" style={styles.button} onPress={this.facebook}>
        </Button>
      </View>
  }
}
```

Here is an image of error:

[image]

Comment: need to see code for next screen

Comment: Have you tried `cd ios`, then `pod install`?, or for android, https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-facebook

Comment: I'm using expo, and i have fixed it, thanks anyway